# How to check the checkbox with the API response in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, api, checkbox, bootstrap-4

API response:

```typescript
{"Business Process(es) selected in Email Authorization":"2,6,10,15","Status":"OK"}
```

My HTML for checkbox:

```typescript
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div *ngFor="let name of processList; index as index;">
        <div class="col-md-3 float-left custom-control custom-checkbox ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="name.Id" [value]="name.Value"
          (change)="saveProcessValues($event)" [(ngModel)]="name.isCheck">
          <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="name.Id">{{name.ColumnName}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

JSON array:

```typescript
  businessProcess = [
    {
      lable: 'Label',
      name: 'defaultInline1',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      lable: 'Renewal Effort',
      name: 'defaultInline2',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      lable: 'Billing Effort',
      name: 'defaultInline3',
      value: 3
    },
    {
      lable: 'Promotion Effort',
      name: 'defaultInline4',
      value: 4
    },
    {
      lable: 'Form Letter',
      name: 'defaultInline5',
      value: 5
    },
    {
      lable: 'Order Item Added',
      name: 'defaultInline6',
      value: 6
    },
    {
      lable: 'Payment Added',
      name: 'defaultInline7',
      value: 7
    },
    {
      lable: 'Order Canceled',
      name: 'defaultInline8',
      value: 8
    },
    {
      lable: 'Order Renewed',
      name: 'defaultInline9',
      value: 9
    },
    {
      lable: 'Password Send',
      name: 'defaultInline10',
      value: 10
    },
    {
      lable: 'Credit Card Failed',
      name: 'defaultInline12',
      value: 12
    },
    {
      lable: 'Email Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline13',
      value: 13
    },
    {
      lable: 'Package Order Added',
      name: 'defaultInline14',
      value: 14
    },
    {
      lable: 'Whole Order Added',
      name: 'defaultInline15',
      value: 15
    },
    {
      lable: 'Package Renewed',
      name: 'defaultInline16',
      value: 16
    },
    {
      lable: 'Password Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline17',
      value: 17
    },
    {
      lable: 'Credit Card Expiry Imminent',
      name: 'defaultInline18',
      value: 18
    },
    {
      lable: 'Login Locked Out',
      name: 'defaultInline19',
      value: 19
    },

    {
      lable: 'Auto-Renewal Imminent',
      name: 'defaultInline20',
      value: 20
    },
    {
      lable: 'Auto-Renewal Failure',
      name: 'defaultInline21',
      value: 21
    },
    {
      lable: 'Suspension Activated',
      name: 'defaultInline22',
      value: 22
    },
    {
      lable: 'Suspension Completed',
      name: 'defaultInline23',
      value: 23
    },
    {
      lable: 'Renewal Status Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline24',
      value: 24
    },
    {
      lable: 'Subscr. ExpireDate Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline25',
      value: 25
    },
    {
      lable: 'Subscr. IssuesLeft Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline26',
      value: 26
    },
    {
      lable: 'Payment Account Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline27',
      value: 27
    },
    {
      lable: 'Subscr. Bundle Quantity Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline28',
      value: 28
    },
    {
      lable: 'Customer Added',
      name: 'defaultInline29',
      value: 29
    },
    {
      lable: 'Customer Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline30',
      value: 30
    },
    {
      lable: 'Customer Login Added',
      name: 'defaultInline31',
      value: 31
    },
    {
      lable: 'Registration Email Send',
      name: 'defaultInline32',
      value: 32
    },
    {
      lable: 'Login Email Send',
      name: 'defaultInline33',
      value: 33
    },
    {
      lable: 'Product Shipped',
      name: 'defaultInline34',
      value: 34
    },
    {
      lable: 'IP Address Changed',
      name: 'defaultInline35',
      value: 35
    },
    {
      lable: 'Deposit Used',
      name: 'defaultInline36',
      value: 36
    },
    {
      lable: 'Group Member Added',
      name: 'defaultInline37',
      value: 37
    },
    {
      lable: 'Group Member Removed',
      name: 'defaultInline38',
      value: 38
    }
  ];
```

Component logic:

```typescript
if (data) {
      this.processList = [];
      const arrayList = this.businessProcess;
      arrayList.forEach(data => {
        const separateName = {
          ColumnName: data.lable,
          Id: data.name,
          Value: data.value
        }
        this.processList.push(separateName);
      });
```

I want the `checkboxes` to be checked when i am getting the response from API....The API response i have mentioned. Suppose values are coming 2,6,10,15 then my `checkboxes` having those values should be checked when the page is loading.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include *any* attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what *you* want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information,  see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be you do not have a boolean property. So after fetching the data changed the `separateName` object like bellow.  Add your logic to `IsCheck` property like bellow. but this is an example. You could change this according to your requirement.

```typescript
arrayList.forEach(data => {
        const separateName = {
          ColumnName: data.lable,
          Id: data.name,
          Value: data.value,
          IsCheck: data.value === 2 || data.value === 6 || data.value === 10 || data.value === 15;
        }
```

Then use the `[(ngModel)]` like bellow

```typescript
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="name.Id" [value]="name.Value" [(ngModel)]="name.IsCheck"
          (change)="saveProcessValues($event)">
```

Also refer their [DOC](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) for more details

Comment: I have 38 check box and their values starting from 1,2,3 and so on upto 38...I have assigned those values in [value].

Comment: ok, then you should use boolean value property for `[(ngModel)]`. I do not know what is the property name of the boolean value that you are using

Comment: {
      lable: 'Label',
      name: 'defaultInline1',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      lable: 'Renewal Effort',
      name: 'defaultInline2',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      lable: 'Billing Effort',
      name: 'defaultInline3',
      value: 3
    },

Comment: hmm seems to be you have to format that json object. So you could use a boolean property. can you update the question with the service call. I will give you a hint then

Comment: hey, did you able to solve this problem?. also make sure to update your question with API request and the response handling part. So if your question is good I will vote to reopen it

Comment: according to your code you are using the same `processList` to render the check boxes. So you should need to have a boolean type property (eg. `IsCheck`). Otherwise you could not able to achieve your goal. you need to handle that `IsCheck` property according to your requirement.  Before passing it to that `processList`

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean variable in your response to identify which checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```
processList=[{"Id":"1","Value":true,"ColumnName":"First",},{"Id":"2","Value":true,"ColumnName":"2nf"},{"Id":"3","Value":false,"ColumnName":"3rd"}]

     <div *ngFor="let name of processList; index as index;">
                  <div class="col-md-3 float-left custom-control custom-checkbox ">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="name.Id" [checked]="name.Value"
                   >
                    <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="name.Id">{{name.ColumnName}}</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

If you don't want to add new boolean flag to track checkboxes then in api response return blank value for checkbox not to be shown as checked.

```
  [checked]="name.Value" replace it with  [(ngModel)]="name.Value"
```

and it will automatically check it value present otherwise will show unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using reactive form in angular then below is the code for it with the use of formcontrolname property we can use it.

in HTML: =

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" formControlName="chkBusiness" class="custom-control-input" id="chkBusiness">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkBusiness">{{'GDPRDATA.CHECKALL' | translate}}</label>
              </div>
```

in TS :=

```
this.gdprForm = this.fb.group({   chkBusiness: [''], });
```

gdprform is the type of formgroup.